# Bad issue "Unexpected token <" with lang.js.php and modx.config.js.php on MODX Revo 2.2.2

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

After installation modx Revo 2.2.2 in manager is only menu without any content.
Dev Tool in Chrome shows errors:

- Uncaught SyntaxError: **Unexpected token <** /connectors/lang.js.php?ctx=mgr&topic=topmenu,file,resource,dashboards&action=53:1
- Uncaught SyntaxError: **Unexpected token <** /connectors/layout/modx.config.js.php?action=53&wctx=mgr:1
- Uncaught ReferenceError: **_ is not defined** /manager/min/index.php?f=/manager/assets/modext/widgets/modx.treedrop.js,/manager/assets/modext/widgets/windows.js,/manager/assets/modext/widgets/resource/modx.tree.resource.js,/manager/assets/modext/widgets/element/modx.tree.element.js,/manager/assets/modext/widgets/system/modx.tree.directory.js,/manager/assets/modext/core/modx.view.js,/manager/assets/modext/core/modx.layout.js:103
  (anonymous function)
- /manager/min/index.php?f=/manager/assets/modext/widgets/modx.treedrop.js,/manager/assets/modext/widgets/windows.js,/manager/assets/modext/widgets/resource/modx.tree.resource.js,/manager/assets/modext/widgets/element/modx.tree.element.js,/manager/assets/modext/widgets/system/modx.tree.directory.js,/manager/assets/modext/core/modx.view.js,/manager/assets/modext/core/modx.layout.js:103
- Uncaught ReferenceError: **_ is not defined** index.php:1

  - MODx.util.JSONReader index.php:1
  - h.Event.name ext-all.js:7
  - b ext-all.js:7
- Uncaught TypeError: **undefined is not a function** ext-all.js:7

  - create ext-all.js:7
  - Ext.extend.load modx.js:74
  - (anonymous function) /manager/?a=53:21
  - h.Event.name ext-all.js:7
  - b ext-all.js:7
- Uncaught ReferenceError: **_ is not defined** index.php:8

  - MODx.page.Dashboards index.php:8
  - create ext-all.js:7
  - Ext.extend.load modx.js:74
  - (anonymous function) /manager/?a=53:26
  - h.Event.name ext-all.js:7

Answer (score 5):

I came across the same problem and it seems that the problem lies in the server configuration.

Turning on `zlib.output_compression`, and setting its level to `5` solved my problem.

This can either be done in your `php.ini` or adding the following lines to your `.htaccess` in your webroot:

```
php_flag zlib.output_compression On
php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < /connectors/lang.js.php?ctx=mgr&topic=topmenu,file,resource,dashboards&action=53:1

means there's a PHP error in the lang.js.php file that is breaking the syntax. Step one should be to find out what the error is - open the file or check the error log (core/cache/logs/error.log). The _ function is defined in that file, causing the cascading errors, so if we can fix that, we can probably get you sorted out.